# Show remaining views depending on radio button selection

Tags: android, layout

I am working on an android app whereby I have a radio button, and depending on the selection of radio button, I want to show either of the two set of input views i.e. if radio button 1 is selected, I want to show a different set of input views, and if radion button 2 is selected, I want to show a different set of input views.

Till now what I've done is that in my activity, I have a radio button, and then I am creating both set of views (but not visible), and when either of radio button is selected, I make one set of views visible.

I believe that is not the "standard" way of doing it, so seeking help on what would be ideal in this case?

Shall I change the workflow to open a new activity depending on which radio button is selected?

Comment: have you tried view.setVisibility(View.GONE) ?  Use View.GONE to completely remove the view so it will not take space on screen.

Comment: You can implement this behavior with fragment, that takes the "choices" as arguments and shows them. Then you can just create a new fragment instance with your desired choices based on selecting the radio button.

Comment: simple approach if you use Constraint Layout map all the views into 2 set of Group and selection of the radio button set the visibility of the group to show and hide if you are not using Constraint Layout you can create groups with view group widget like Linear Layout Or Relative and show and hide them and by setting 1 view all the views will be hidden or shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to separate each layout and its logic to separate files.

The best solution to do that is to use `Fragments` and each fragment will have its own layout xml file and Kotlin/Java class for coding.

## Implementation

First, you have to create two fragments.

#### FirstFragment.kt

```kotlin
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }
}
```

#### fragment_first.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#336699"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="First Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

#### SecondFragment.kt

```kotlin
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }
}
```

#### fragment_second.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#996633"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Second Fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now, in your activity you need to create the `RadioGroup` with two `RadioButtons`, then add `FragmentContainerView` which will be the container for all fragments.

#### activity_main.xml

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View 1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="View 2"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/radio_group"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The final step is to implement the fragment changes in activity when the user changes the `RadioButton` selection.

#### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var radioGroup : RadioGroup

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group)
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            when(checkedId){
                R.id.radio_1 -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, FirstFragment()).commit()
                R.id.radio_2 -> supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, SecondFragment()).commit()
            }
        }
        radioGroup.check(R.id.radio_1) // To check the first radio by default
    }
}
```

## Results

- When the first `RadioButton` is selected

[image: view_1]

- When the second `RadioButton` is selected

[image: view_2]